# Кнопка "Показать еще"

Tags: javascript

Помогите с помощью js сделать кнопку "Показать еще", чтобы она выводила контент порциями по 3 штуки, а именно li
код прилагаю:

```html
<div class="products">
<ul>
<li>один</li>
<li>два</li>
<li>три</li>
<li>четыре</li>
<li>пять</li>
<li>шесть</li>
<li>семь</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам нужно подгружать информацию из бд аджаксом, или Вам нужно просто открывать скрытые li ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Универсальный вариант, если таких списков много:

```js
let step = 3; // Размер этих самых порций. Чтобы легко можно было поменять.
let prod = document.querySelectorAll('.products');

for( let i = 0; i < prod.length; i++ ){
  let product = prod[i];
  let li = product.querySelectorAll('li');
  for( let j = 0; j < step; j++ ){//Для начала перебираем - показываем первые step пунктов.
    // Но только если такие существуют
    if( li[j] ){ li[j].classList.add('visi') }
  }
  
  let more = product.querySelector('.more');
  more.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let visi = product.querySelectorAll('.visi');
    let next = visi[visi.length-1].nextElementSibling;
    // Достали следующий элемент ПОСЛЕДНЕГО элемента visi. 
    //Предполагается, что никогда не будет добавлено полностью пустых ul.
    let it = 0;
    while( it < step ){
      if( next ){
        next.classList.add('visi');
        next = next.nextElementSibling;
        it++;
      } else {
        break; // Если следующего элемента не оказалось - выключаем цикл.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.products {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.products li { display: none; }
.products .visi {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <button class="more">Исчо</button>
  <ul>
    <li>один</li>
    <li>два</li>
    <li>три</li>
    <li>четыре</li>
    <li>пять</li>
    <li>шесть</li>
    <li>семь</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="products">
  <button class="more">Исчо</button>
  <ul>
    <li>один</li>
    <li>два</li>
    <li>три</li>
    <li>четыре</li>
    <li>пять</li>
    <li>шесть</li>
    <li>семь</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="products">
  <button class="more">Исчо</button>
  <ul>
    <li>один</li>
    <li>два</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно

Comment: Подскажите, а как сделать так, чтобы после того как были показаны все элементы кнопка исчезала?

Comment: @VitaliyAntal В предпоследней строчке, перед `});` добавить `this.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Неправильно работает, после первого нажатия на кнопку, она сразу исчезает